# WIll a hero with damage over time die if he is banished?

Tags: dota-2

Suppose a hero has a doom casted on it and when he is about to die, I put him in astral imprisonment, so will he continue taking damage even when he is banished?

There are more damage over time spells and shadow demon also has a banishing spell. So what happen in those cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, being banished  (Astral Emprisonnement, Disruption, Phase Shift etc.) makes your hero invulnerable.

The only exception to this rule is Sanity's Eclipse (which does not deal damage over time) that can damage you while you are Astral Emprisonned.

Being Banished in any form does not pause a debuff timer (like a DOT or a stun) which allow you to negate some part of the damage when you are banished.

Comment: ok. it seems that i missed a little detail here. will the counter keep ticking? say if the hero with doom is about to die in the next 2 seconds and i banish him for more than 2 seconds, will he survive or it will start taking damage over time from where he was before he was banished after coming out?

Comment: @MandeepJain edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Banish makes a target invulnerable, except from the hero that banished them. Sanity's Eclipse works through Astral Imprisonment, and Soul Catcher, Shadow Poison and Demonic Purge all affect targets within Disruption.

Phase Shift makes you immune to everything.

A Damage over time spell will continue to tick while banished, but do no damage. 
e.g. A hero that is Doomed and has 3 more seconds of it left will not take any damage if he is Astraled. If 6 seconds left, he will take only 2 ticks of damage, assuming Astral Imprisonment is at max level.

Comment: in dota 1 this would be different. at least bottle would be paused and therefore the heal effect prolonged. in dota 2 there is no pause effect. maybe thats the difference